# Conversion from string "<fetch version='1.0' ><entity na" to type 'Double' is not valid."

Tags: c#, vb.net, dynamics-crm

I am reading a string attribute from ms crm in temp string variable then i am converting it to type integer memcod so that i need to pass it as integer type to xml but it sounds strange i am not using a string or double its throws the following exception **Conversion from string "`<fetch version='1.0' ><entity na`" to type 'Double' is not valid.** Please help[image: exception]

Comment: http://idownvotedyoubecause.com/so/ImageOfAnException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you tried to concatenate a bunch of strings together with an integer, `memcod`, by using the `+` operator.

This code produces the same exception at runtime:

> Conversion from string "<foo>" to type 'Double' is not valid.

```
Dim n as Integer = 0
Dim test As String = "<foo>" +
        n +
        "</foo>"
```

Clearly, VB sees the integer there and thinks that you're trying to do arithmetic. I guess it figures you want a `double` because it can't hazard a guess what else you might want. This bizarre code, for example, sets `test` to `"11"`. [That's a *string* equal to `"11"`](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/Trollface.png):

```
    Dim n As Integer = 0
    Dim test As String = "5" +
        n +
        "6"
```

You can work around this issue in two ways.

One, [use VB's backwards compatible dedicated string concatenation operator](https://cdn.meme.am/instances/57248909.jpg) instead of `+`:

```
    Dim test As String = "<foo>" &
        n &
        "</foo>"
```

Two, [explicitly stringify `n`](http://i1.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/facebook/000/862/065/0e9.jpg):

```
    Dim test As String = "<foo>" +
        n.ToString() +
        "</foo>"
```

Comment: Or even more convenient: `String.Concat("<foo>", n, "</foo>")`

Comment: @AlexB. Personally, I find concatenation-by-operator more pleasant to write and maintain. Given my druthers, it's `$"<foo>{n}</foo>"` all day long, but VB won't druther me that one of course.

Comment: string.concat has the nice effect that you don´t have to cast non-strings - like numbers - to string first.

Comment: Dim test As String = "<foo>" &
        n &
        "</foo>"   worked awesome for me thank you Ed plunkett